# 12.5 Xcode beta makes this work, Won't work regular 12.4 - "Use of local variable before is declaration"

Tags: swift, xcode

So I built a project, and I'm ready to update my app on the AppStore with the latest updates.. I was working in 12.5 beta at the time I tried to upload to AppStore so of course I get the error saying I need to use the production version of Xcode.. once I go back to Xcode 12.4 I get this error in my source code ..

"Use of local variable before its declaration"

its referring to this code

```
 struct MyStruct {
     
    var exampleProperty: Int

       init() {
    
    
     self.exampleProperty = myConversionFunc()

     func myConversionFunc() -> Int {...}
    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Literally moving the func before the property in the init solved the problem in Xcode 12.4 and its absolutely doesn't matter in 12.5